# Can I use conditional (ternary) operator in [ngClass] alongside with multiple class conditions in Angular2?

Tags: angular, conditional-operator, ng-class

I can use multiple conditions like that:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'checked': isChecked, 'disabled': isDisabled}">
```

And conditional (ternary) operator like that:

```
<div [ngClass]="isEmpty ? 'empty-class' : 'not-empty-class'">
```

Is there a way to combine multiple conditions with ternary operator? Something like the following which isn't working:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'checked': isChecked, 'disabled': isDisabled, isEmpty ? 'empty-class' : 'not-empty-class'}">
```

A workaround would be to use the following syntax:

````
<div [class.checked]="isChecked" 
     [class.disabled]="isDisabled"
     [ngClass]="isEmpty ? 'empty-class' : 'not-empty-class'">```
````

Comment: I don't understand the reason to use ternary in binary mode. Split it to two binaries: {'empty-class': isEmpty, 'not-empty-class': !isEmpty} :D

Comment: @Roberc There is no special reason, there are many workarounds. I suggest one already. I just wanted to know if it can be done.

Comment: a side note, I would `[ngClass]="stateClasses"` ? and populate that on my `ngOnInit()` by calling a private function that does the complex logic and returns a concatenated list of all needed classes. this would evaluate things once instead of **re-evaluating the ternary on each change detection**.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the reason why would you want to do that. But, no, you cannot do that.

According to the [API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description), you can only provide array, string or object. So in your case, you are providing object, where they keys represents the class name, and the values represent the condition, i.e. truthy or falsy.

The way you can use ternary operator is:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'checked': isChecked, 'empty-class': somefunction() ? true: false}">
```

But again, it's just unnecessary code, which should be replaced by

```
<div [ngClass]="{'checked': isChecked, 'empty-class': somefunction()}">
```